# A very small part of an office building is gone, leaving vacuum. How does this affect its surroundings?

Tags: science-based, atmosphere, vacuum

A small perfect sphere is suddenly *gone*. Everything inside is teleported somewhere -- through space or even maybe through time, we're not sure. It's a small sphere, just enough to fit a human sitting on a chair. The perfect vaporization affects everything -- most of the chair, large part of the desk, air. What's left behind is just vacuum. No flash, no explosion, no sound. (The fact that this can happen is the only part I can/want to handwave, but bonus points for a reality check here.)

But what happens to this space moments after it happens? **What would a blob of empty space do when placed in the atmosphere** -- precisely, in an office full of tech equipment. Would there *be* an explosion after all? Would it create an energy blast? Would it feel like a wind coming from it or going towards it? Could it do something to the laptops and phones nearby?

Comment: There is a kind of underwater crustacean that does exactly this: it retracts it's tail so fast that water can't keep up with this speed. It results in pressure explosion that kills nearby plankton creatures.

Comment: I edited the title so that "part of the world" would not imply "part of the **Earth**".  If  you disagree with it, feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino yet there is a significant difference in density between water and air...

Comment: [Here's a effect like this decribed](https://what-if.xkcd.com/6/)

Comment: You can observe an artistic impression of this phenomenon at the conclusion of the *[Adama Maneuver](https://youtu.be/3AjXgY35iZg?t=1m39s)* (if I may say, an *outstanding* scene in my humble opinion)

Comment: You say this needs handwaving, but we don't know that this can't be done. In fact, if some theories on wormhole generation to access multiple universes is true, the only requirement would be a short-lived wormhole in a specifically targeted location.

Comment: @Jannis I came here specifically to add that - with the text, "Very badly"

Comment: @Wayne Werner what ??? i literally dont understand which text and whats 'so badly', im always tying to improve so could you specify what you mean?

Comment: I meant that removing a very small part of an office building, leaving behind a vacuum would affect it's surroundings very badly. Of course, when you read the OPs question they're really asking about remove mostly air, along with a human, which has almost nothing to do with the building. Which would react very poorly to having parts of it removed, especially if they were load bearing.

Comment: @WayneWerner I want to tell you that in my link it was just a glass with some cm³, that lead to massive whirling of the water, but if you're removing a hole m³ or even a half the effect gets bigger... and its not about what got removed

Comment: @Jannis I know. I'm very familiar with the what-ifs :) The title of this question is "a very small part of an office building is gone, leaving a vacuum. How does this affect its surroundings?" "Very badly" is the answer, with the xkcd as the explanation of why "very badly" is the answer.

Comment: @WayneWerner Ohh I get it, in my language 'very badly' means not the opposite of 'hardly', but just being bad at schoool. I thought at first the text(link) is so bad, but you meant it as conclusion of the text. Im so sry for that misstake of myself :L

Comment: @Jannis today we learned :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A very similar question was covered in [What if](https://what-if.xkcd.com/6/) series, applied to a glass.

Quoting from there:

> We’ll imagine the vacuums appear at time $t=0$.
>
> For the first handful of microseconds, nothing happens. On this timescale, even the air molecules are nearly stationary. For the most part, air molecules jiggle around at speeds of a few hundred meters per second. But at any given time, some happen to be moving faster than others. The fastest few are moving at over 1000 meters per second. These are the first to drift into the vacuum.
>
> After a few hundred microseconds, the air rushing into the glass on the right fills the vacuum completely and rams into the surface of the water, sending a pressure wave through the liquid. The sides of the glass bulge slightly, but they contain the pressure and do not break. A shockwave reverberates through the water and back into the air, joining the turbulence already there.
>
> In a few more milliseconds, it reaches the humans’ ears as a loud bang.

The bang will be pretty loud. I happened once to force open a vacuum chamber not yet fully vented, and though it was not in deep vacuum (just few millibar) it sounded like somebody had given a strong hit with a hammer.

Maybe the shockwave would be strong enough to shatter some fragile glass and damage some MEMS (like the microphones in the telephones).

Comment: If you're vacuum chamber did the sound of a hammer something $5m^3$ big would probably shatter all the windows of the house and the vase of your mother-in-law

Comment: Note - the answer to this question depends on what the OP means by "small".   If it is 10cm there would be a POP.  If a meter a big bang and shaking.  If 10m there would surely be a hurricane-earthquake like effect.

Comment: @Fattie, OP states "enough to fit a human sitting on a chair". That's about 80 $dm^3$, or 80 liters.

Comment: I'm not the asker, but I'd love a physicist to chime in about atoms splitting at the edges, too. If the volume removed has a mathematically precise edge, then aren't we inevitably splitting atoms, and even sub-atomic particles, to the extent that they can be considered to be in a specific place?

Comment: good one, I missed that @L.Dutch

Comment: @whybird , you make an excellent point.  Any hypothetical sci-fi device which "removes from existence!" "everything" would deeply deal with issues such as the nature of a vacuum (we have no clue), what particles are (we have less than a clue), the nature of spacetime (we know less than nothing), the nature of quantum reality (we know explicitly nothing) and "trivial" issues like quantum gravity (we've reached the point of knowing we know nothing).  Bearing in mind that the whole idea is ***staggeringly impossible*** and hand-wavium based - I'm not sure if any definitve answers could be given!

Comment: @L.Dutch, a human may occupy a volume of 80 liter, but a perfect sphere surrounding that human while sitting would contain about 4pi(.75)^3/3 = 1.77 m^3 = 1770 l

Comment: {For example, just one random thought, that small volume would have a small amount of **dark matter** (or perhaps dark energy .. or cold dark matter, or hot dark matter .. or maybe scalar dark matter {which as we all know is merely a Bose-Einstein condensate of quantas, a very strange thing indeed} ... what happens when we eviscerate a blob of dark matter?  Who knows!}

Comment: @Fattie If the removal follow a precisely defined edge, then we also have to consider the uncertainty principle. Though the volume of space being emptied might be precisely defined, the position of particles isn't. So every particle will randomly be removed or not removed, but for particles far from the edge the probability will be close to 0% or 100%. But is this going to work out in such a way that entire molecules end up on the same side with a certain probability distribution among the two sides, or will it split molecules and maybe even atoms?

Comment: @Fattie My thinking is that probably it would be entirely possible to split molecules this way. And the electrons are not really tightly coupled to a specific atom anymore, so it's also quite likely that once split we may end up with some ions along the edge and some chemical reactions will happen involving those after the split. But atom nucleus are small enough that those might not be split because the uncertainty principle will have them randomly show up on one side or the other of the split. Protons and neutrons can't be split as quarks cannot exist in isolation.

Comment: @Fattie - I agree about the levels of unknown involved. I suspect a reasonable physics -based answer for story purposes would be that there might be a momentary sparkle at the edges as we split a few atoms. Not enough to be dangerous, I expect, as 99.99%+ of the volume of any given atom is just electron cloud, and removing electrons is nothing very new (but again, spark(le)s).  Maybe some of the wood and metal etc molecules in the desk/floor/etc get transformed into some slightly unusual molecules.

Comment: @kasperd - I’m not a physicist, but I understand that quarks etc. exist alone for a few microseconds before they are annihilated  by quantum effects, and those are in fact exactly what we see in particle colliders. But I think it is reasonable that electrons, quarks etc near the edge would quantum-field collapse to one side or the other. At that scale, they don’t really even *have* such a thing as a position, so logically they can’t be split.

Comment: @whybird The explanation which is usually given for why you cannot separate a quark is that as you are pulling away one quark you are putting energy into the system with the work you are doing. And at a certain distance you have put enough energy into the system that all of that energy turns into a quark/anti-quark pair. The quark will fly back to the origin of the quark you are pulling away while the anti-quark will catch up with the quark you are pulling away and annihilate it producing a pair of gamma particles. (Take with a grain of salt, I am not a particle physicist.)

Comment: How did you manage to open the door to the vacuum chamber while there was still a significant pressure differential?

Comment: @eirikdaude Many vacuum chambers have vertically sliding doors, which are less impacted by pressure differential than swing-doors.  (This relates to why trains have sliding doors, so that they don't burst open when passing each other or entering/leaving a tunnel)

Comment: @Chronocidal Ah, all the ones I've used have had swinging doors. Different uses, I guess :)

Comment: We have to remember that this example uses water - water that is incompressible and has significantly more mass per unit volume than air.  I suspect that you would get a "pop" and a small breeze, but beyond that the biggest effect will be due to the reactions of any witnesses.

Comment: @Baldrickk I assume that this is why L.Dutch has only used the example of "Empty in the Top half", with "it makes a bang" and not the example of "Empty in the Bottom half" with "it makes an explosion"

Comment: @Chronocidal indeed, but also the xkcd has an enclosed vacumn.  The situation posed in the question would have a few remnants of a desk (edge on) and part of the floor (at a tangent) as the items immediately surrounding the vacuum. the inrushing air would meet only air coming from the other side, as opposed to a mass of air 'slapping' the water.

Comment: @Baldrickk Pressure gradients cause a bang.  The most famous example of this is the classic "double boom" of supersonic aircraft - the first boom is caused by compressed air (like bursting a balloon) and the second is produced by a negative pressure gradient (like our collapsing vacuum)

Comment: @Chronocidal yes. but is our situation here big enough to make a big bang like that, or a smaller one?  I honestly don't know here, but my intuition would suggest it would be more like a balloon popping than a fighter jet breaking the sound barrier.  I may be wrong.

Comment: Deep vacuum doesn't matter.  A few millibar is basically a vacuum.  The difference between a rough vacuum and a deep vacuum is like 99.99% vs 99.999999%.  In terms of potential energy (to produce a force or shockwave), there is really nothing gained with a high or ultrahigh vacuum.  The only need for ultrahigh vacuum is cleanliness - when you need to keep dirty air molecules off of your perfect surfaces and out of your carefully pure materials.

Comment: This answer is somewhat incomplete in that it doesn't address how the air rushing into fill the void affects the surrounding room.  If this spot was in a small office, the overall density of the air in the room would be significantly reduced.  As the from the room fills the void, the air pressure would therefore be lower than the atmosphere.  If the room were closed, this might mean windows would shatter inward due to the imbalance between the outside and inside or doors could be blown open/off their hinges for the same reason.

Comment: @JimmyJames, a small room 5 x 5 x 3 meters would account for 7500 liters of air. 80 liters are just 1% of that volume. An office would be way bigger than that, further lowering the relative magnitude.

Comment: @L.Dutch 5X5X3 is a huge office.  It's a pretty big room in general (over 16 feet wide and long.)  I have a bedroom in my house half that size if not smaller.  The first office (that I shared with another person) was maybe the size of a cube 2.5 meters on all sides.  Single-person offices were maybe a little more than half of that.  More like 5% to 9%.

Comment: @JimmyJames that would really depend on what kind of office we have here. My opinion is even if the office is large, but the bubble disappeared next to a window, that widow would shatter.

Comment: @Alexander Right, it's quite possible depending on a lot of factors.  I guess my point is that the sudden reduction in air pressure in the vicinity would cause imbalances.  It *could* be similar to what happens in extreme weather when a sudden drop in pressure blows the windows out of cars and houses depending on various details of the scenario.  It's not just the pressure wave from the noise.  The windows would have atmospheric pressure on the outside pushing in and something less pushing out for a few moments.

Answer (score 18):

> What would a blob of empty space do when placed in the atmosphere -- precisely, in an office full of tech equipment. Would there be an explosion after all? Would it create an energy blast? Would it feel like a wind coming from it or going towards it? Could it do something to the laptops and phones nearby?

The same thing that happens *after* a lightning strike heats up the air so much that the hot gasses expand, causing a partial vacuum where the lightning was: air rushes back in **really fast** because *nature abhors a vacuum*.

And we all know what goes with lightning: a really loud **thunder clap** that -- if close enough -- breaks glass and sets off car alarms when the rapidly in-rushing air bounces against other bits of in-rushing air and bounces back.

Comment: Not clear how expanding gas would cause a vacuum. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunder, a thunderclap is caused by the rapid expansion itself, not by a vacuum (unless you're going with the 19th-century theory).

Comment: @LarsH it's the rebound *after* the rapid expansion.  That very well might be the 19th century theory (I'm old enough to have been taught "New" Math instead of just Math...) but the Wikipedia article starts by saying "**Thunder** is the sound caused by **clouds rubbing together**" and that's more than a bit dubious...

Comment: For *nature abhorring vacuum* there is quite a lot of it around in space. The opposite appears to be rather true. ;)

Comment: I never liked the phrase ‘Nature abhors a vaccuum’. It’s objectively wrong. Nature loves vaccuum. It loves it so much that it’s doing its best to make sure all the matter is in dense lumps so it can enjoy untrammelled vaccuum for lightyears and lightyears. Even on a smaller scale: molecules love vaccuum, it briefly stops them being jostled by their neighbors!! </pointless rant> Good answer!

Comment: Dammit @Battle, ninj’d in pedantry!!

Comment: Sounds like by "rebound" you mean a rapid contraction. Putting that into your explanation between "hot gasses expand" and "causing a partial vacuum" would make it quite a bit clearer. Re: "clouds rubbing together" - yeah, that does a lot for Wikipedia's credibility. :-/

Comment: @Battle My understanding is that space is not a perfect vacuum?

Comment: @Onyz - "Perfect" often sets unreachable standards. But sure, there are particles floating around in space, but the density is minuscule... meaning it is still a vacuum, even though not "perfect." https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-density-of-space

Comment: @JoeBloggs Any explanation that requires anthropomorphic desires by nature is bad physics.

Comment: @JimmyJames: Next you’ll be telling me chickens aren’t actually spherical!!

Comment: @JoeBloggs How about "Nature abhors human-scale vacuums"? System-scale ones are all over the place, and intermolecular ones abound, but at scales humans live at, Nature generally loves vacuums so much that it needs to get all up close and personal ASAP.

Comment: @NicHartley: Nature loves human scale vacuums *too much*.

Answer (score 5):

This is somewhat similar to the situation in a "vacuum cannon" - one of those research/demonstration devices where they accelerate light objects like ping pong balls or meteorite models to very high speeds, way past mach 1, by

The problem is, there's always extra noise involved with those, like breaking the diaphragms and the thing they're firing hitting stuff.

My guess here is that it would be very noticeable but not very damaging=there would be a sudden wind towards the hole and a drop in pressure that would really thump your eardrums, but any kind of sonic wave from the air colliding in the middle of the hole would be almost nothing because its surrounded by a much bigger shell of rarified air, blowing directly towards it. Even if you were right at the boundary when it disappeared, I can't see it would be any different than a very very hard gust of wind.

I can't see how there could be any supersonic effects or any overpressures over 1 bar, outside a spherical void, because all the energy and air involved in the middle would have to reduce the pressure and total energy outside the void... which geometrically is going to be bigger (although that effect obviously goes away the bigger the void is, until at some huge size you could pretend the boundry was a flat plane i guess)

Now if the area that suddeny becomes vacuum had some interesting shapes, I think you could produce weird jet effects by changing the shape, but i still dont see how you can transfer much energy outside the area if the entire area disappears at one time. Those vacuum cannons work by breaking the membranes at different times.

TLDR: i think people right at the boundary would get blasted off their feet by wind or smashed by cars or buildings blowing onto them. They wouldn't have permanent hearing damage or even burst eardrums, but they'd all go OW what was that whomp noise. They would all get really cold really fast but very briefly, and there might be a wave of sudden white mist that went away in seconds.

people standing around 2 radiuses or more from the center of the void would probably just feel a strong gust of wind and hear a huge WHOMP noise, and 3 or 4 radiuses people would just hear a weird echoey whomp.

super short still TL still DR: I think it would be pretty underwhelming, there's a lot less kinetic energy involved than a small bomb or something, and less transmission of it.

Answer (score 5):

Mini sonic boom as the air rushes in to fill in the empty space.  It's not really a huge volume of air but people within a meter (yard) would certainly feel both the suction as well as feel the concussion of the rebound, papers would be tossed around the room, books/binders may be pulled off of shelves.  People within several meters would certainly feel the momentary pressure differential, calenders would wave as the air rushed past to fill in the space.  People further away wouldn't feel much, if anything at all, but would certainly hear the bang which would sound like something like a large firecracker (but probably not as big as an M80).

A more interesting question would be:  If this is the way your teleporter works, what happens at the place where the matter re-materializes?

**Edit:** Coincidentally I was just watching *Predestination*, which is a time travel movie, and I think they depict this very well.  When the time traveler leaves one place everything in the room is sucked in the direction of where he was.  At the place where he materializes everything is pushed back out of the way as if momentarily blown by a strong wind.

Just an added perspective.

Comment: When I think about teleporters, I always want them to swap the content of two volumes rather than just removing one, to avoud as much matter-overlap at the receiving end as possible. BUT, to maintain causality, there still has to be at minimum a light-speed delay between the contents of one volume leaving and the other arriving (at both ends). Depending on the distance involved, this could easily be significant, and presumably there is a total vacuum in the meantime... and even if the delay is short, SOME atoms at the edges will have drifted in.

Comment: @whybird Thanks for chiming in -- the "distance" covered is zero because the movement happens through time planes.

Comment: There is *only* spacetime.

Answer (score 1):

It's not directly answer to your question but it's based on one of comments:

> the idea is that a sphere slips through time while duplicating itself -- like cell division, but through time (not space). This leads to whatever taking its place from another time plane (chances are that it's a chunk of outer space). One duplicate goes to whatever, while the other duplicate creates a new time-plane. I guess that I'll need to anchor the spheres from time-planes into same or similar Earth coordinates (something with gravity?) to **avoid the sound and wind. It has to be mostly unnoticeable.**

Make the sphere 4D with time as fourth dimension. This way the empty space won't be an immediate one but gradual which means the pressure just drops slightly and gradually while the 4D sphere moves out of the current time plane. You can set the timing as you please to avoid sudden rush of air and limit any other unsuitable effects.

Let's assume we have a standard open-space. In the building I currently work a single floor area is around $2100 m^2$. The height of a floor is aroung $3 m$ giving a volume of $6300 m^3$. A sitting person has height of roughly $1.4 m$ so a 3D sphere that is the intersection of 4D sphere and the current time plane has a volume of

$$
V_S = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 = \pi \cdot \frac{4}{3} \cdot (\frac{7}{10})^3 \approx 1.5 \space (m^3)
$$

So it occupies as little as 0.24% of total space. If the original pressure was 1013 hPa (an average atmospheric pressure), with a gradual change after it completes the pressure will drop to 1012.76 hPa

For comparison, when flying on a typical airliner, the pressure drops in about 20 minutes (the ascending time) from the ground pressure (1013 hPa on average) to the pressure that exists on 7000 ft, which is approximately 782 hPa. It means the pressure drops 11.55 hPa per minute. If you've ever flown a plane you know there are no visible signs, however your body does react to some level - yet this is mainly due to *significant* overall change in pressure. If your process of bubble split is gradual as I suggest and takes about 1.5 second the pressure drop rate will be comparable to that in a plane but due to the extremely small pressure difference and time of it, it will go totally unnoticeable to anyone. It is also not going to affect any equipment.

The interesting side effect is that the phenomenon will cause some kind of time turbulence while moving bubble to a different time plane but there is your hand-wave area as this is something due to the mechanics of your process and you can decide on the impact of it yourself (e.g. the time might fluctuate for a moment near the bubble so you can notice a clock seconds hand stops for 2 seconds rather than 1 only to jump twice in the next second.

---

Some links to back this up

- [Sitting human height](http://donsnotes.com/reference/size-humans.html)
- [Plane cabin pressurization explained](https://aerosavvy.com/aircraft-pressurization/)
- [Air pressure calculator](https://www.mide.com/pages/air-pressure-at-altitude-calculator) (use the second one!)
- Sorry, I couldn't find anything about time turbulence caused by the 4D sphere moving through time planes, but someone might get more lucky with better Google query ;-)